# font-weight bold is messing up the alignment of input boxes

Tags: html, css

[This is what I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7UQJ.png)

[This is what i'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvswD.png)

Here is my code. The problem is that when I try to turn the label text bold using "font-weight" it goes out of alignment. But without it the alignment is fine.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  background-image: url("1.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

h1 {
  text-align: right;
  display: block;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
  display: block;
}

div {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 90%;
}

div * {
  flex: 1;
}

input[type="text"] {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<h1>Evergreen Valley College Survey</h1>
<p class="right"><a href="https://www.google.com">Email webmaster</a> |
  <a href="https://www.google.com">Evergreen Valley College Website</a></p>
<h2>Personal Information</h2>
<div>
  <form>
    <label for="fname">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
    <br>
    <label for="mail">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean it goes out of alignment?

Comment: @TheCodesee The font weight is pushing the bottom input a little to the right so it's not aligned with the box above it

Comment: @j08691 Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a coincidence that the two inputs are aligned in the first case. To be sure of getting what you want, you have to give a fixed width to the labels:

```
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: It's working. Can you explain what the inline-block is doing here.

Comment: @FakhrAli You can't set a width on an inline level element hence `display: inline-block;`